# How to include dependencies in google analytics

Tags: html, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to create and show custom dashboard of google analytics in my own website. I am following tuts on [ga-dev-tools](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/) to achieve this. Problem is i am unable to add components and dependencies including **view-selector2.js**, **date-range-selector.js** and **active-users.js**. I am unable to find these files anywhere on google as well. when i paste the code given on [third party visualizations](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/) it says **view-selector2.js**, **date-range-selector.js** and **active-users.js** files not found in console. 
Here is my code so far

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Custom Components Google Analytics</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            (function (w, d, s, g, js, fs) {
                g = w.gapi || (w.gapi = {});
                g.analytics = {q: [], ready: function (f) {
                        this.q.push(f);
                    }};
                js = d.createElement(s);
                fs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                js.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
                fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fs);
                js.onload = function () {
                    g.load('analytics');
                };
            }(window, document, 'script'));
        </script>

        <div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
        <div id="view-selector-container"></div>
        <div id="active-users-container"></div>
        <div id="chart-1-container"></div>
        <div id="legend-1-container"></div>
        <div id="chart-2-container"></div>
        <div id="legend-2-container"></div>
        <div id="chart-3-container"></div>
        <div id="legend-3-container"></div>
        <div id="chart-4-container"></div>
        <div id="legend-4-container"></div>

        <!-- Include the ViewSelector2 component script. -->
        <script src="/public/javascript/embed-api/view-selector2.js"></script>

        <!-- Include the DateRangeSelector component script. -->
        <script src="/public/javascript/embed-api/date-range-selector.js"></script>
        <script>

            gapi.analytics.ready(function () {

                /**
                 * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
                 * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
                 * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
                 */
                gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
                    container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
                    clientid: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                });


                /**
                 * Create a new ActiveUsers instance to be rendered inside of an
                 * element with the id "active-users-container" and poll for changes every
                 * five seconds.
                 */
                var activeUsers = new gapi.analytics.ext.ActiveUsers({
                    container: 'active-users-container',
                    pollingInterval: 5
                });


                /**
                 * Add CSS animation to visually show the when users come and go.
                 */
                activeUsers.once('success', function () {
                    var element = this.container.firstChild;
                    var timeout;

                    this.on('change', function (data) {
                        var element = this.container.firstChild;
                        var animationClass = data.delta > 0 ? 'is-increasing' : 'is-decreasing';
                        element.className += (' ' + animationClass);

                        clearTimeout(timeout);
                        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                            element.className =
                                    element.className.replace(/ is-(increasing|decreasing)/g, '');
                        }, 3000);
                    });
                });


                /**
                 * Create a new ViewSelector2 instance to be rendered inside of an
                 * element with the id "view-selector-container".
                 */
                var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ext.ViewSelector2({
                    container: 'view-selector-container',
                })
                        .execute();


                /**
                 * Update the activeUsers component, the Chartjs charts, and the dashboard
                 * title whenever the user changes the view.
                 */
                viewSelector.on('viewChange', function (data) {
                    var title = document.getElementById('view-name');
                    title.innerHTML = data.property.name + ' (' + data.view.name + ')';

                    // Start tracking active users for this view.
                    activeUsers.set(data).execute();

                    // Render all the of charts for this view.
                    renderWeekOverWeekChart(data.ids);
                    renderYearOverYearChart(data.ids);
                    renderTopBrowsersChart(data.ids);
                    renderTopCountriesChart(data.ids);
                });


                /**
                 * Draw the a chart.js line chart with data from the specified view that
                 * overlays session data for the current week over session data for the
                 * previous week.
                 */
                function renderWeekOverWeekChart(ids) {

                    // Adjust `now` to experiment with different days, for testing only...
                    var now = moment(); // .subtract(3, 'day');

                    var thisWeek = query({
                        'ids': ids,
                        'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:nthDay',
                        'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
                        'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        'end-date': moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                    });

                    var lastWeek = query({
                        'ids': ids,
                        'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:nthDay',
                        'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
                        'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(0).subtract(1, 'week')
                                .format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        'end-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(6).subtract(1, 'week')
                                .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                    });

                    Promise.all([thisWeek, lastWeek]).then(function (results) {

                        var data1 = results[0].rows.map(function (row) {
                            return +row[2];
                        });
                        var data2 = results[1].rows.map(function (row) {
                            return +row[2];
                        });
                        var labels = results[1].rows.map(function (row) {
                            return +row[0];
                        });

                        labels = labels.map(function (label) {
                            return moment(label, 'YYYYMMDD').format('ddd');
                        });

                        var data = {
                            labels: labels,
                            datasets: [
                                {
                                    label: 'Last Week',
                                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                                    data: data2
                                },
                                {
                                    label: 'This Week',
                                    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                                    data: data1
                                }
                            ]
                        };

                        new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-1-container')).Line(data);
                        generateLegend('legend-1-container', data.datasets);
                    });
                }


                /**
                 * Draw the a chart.js bar chart with data from the specified view that
                 * overlays session data for the current year over session data for the
                 * previous year, grouped by month.
                 */
                function renderYearOverYearChart(ids) {

                    // Adjust `now` to experiment with different days, for testing only...
                    var now = moment(); // .subtract(3, 'day');

                    var thisYear = query({
                        'ids': ids,
                        'dimensions': 'ga:month,ga:nthMonth',
                        'metrics': 'ga:users',
                        'start-date': moment(now).date(1).month(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        'end-date': moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                    });

                    var lastYear = query({
                        'ids': ids,
                        'dimensions': 'ga:month,ga:nthMonth',
                        'metrics': 'ga:users',
                        'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'year').date(1).month(0)
                                .format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        'end-date': moment(now).date(1).month(0).subtract(1, 'day')
                                .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                    });

                    Promise.all([thisYear, lastYear]).then(function (results) {
                        var data1 = results[0].rows.map(function (row) {
                            return +row[2];
                        });
                        var data2 = results[1].rows.map(function (row) {
                            return +row[2];
                        });
                        var labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

                        // Ensure the data arrays are at least as long as the labels array.
                        // Chart.js bar charts don't (yet) accept sparse datasets.
                        for (var i = 0, len = labels.length; i < len; i++) {
                            if (data1[i] === undefined)
                                data1[i] = null;
                            if (data2[i] === undefined)
                                data2[i] = null;
                        }

                        var data = {
                            labels: labels,
                            datasets: [
                                {
                                    label: 'Last Year',
                                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                    data: data2
                                },
                                {
                                    label: 'This Year',
                                    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                    data: data1
                                }
                            ]
                        };

                        new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-2-container')).Bar(data);
                        generateLegend('legend-2-container', data.datasets);
                    })
                            .catch(function (err) {
                                console.error(err.stack);
                            })
                }


                /**
                 * Draw the a chart.js doughnut chart with data from the specified view that
                 * show the top 5 browsers over the past seven days.
                 */
                function renderTopBrowsersChart(ids) {

                    query({
                        'ids': ids,
                        'dimensions': 'ga:browser',
                        'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
                        'sort': '-ga:pageviews',
                        'max-results': 5
                    })
                            .then(function (response) {

                                var data = [];
                                var colors = ['#4D5360', '#949FB1', '#D4CCC5', '#E2EAE9', '#F7464A'];

                                response.rows.forEach(function (row, i) {
                                    data.push({value: +row[1], color: colors[i], label: row[0]});
                                });

                                new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-3-container')).Doughnut(data);
                                generateLegend('legend-3-container', data);
                            });
                }


                /**
                 * Draw the a chart.js doughnut chart with data from the specified view that
                 * compares sessions from mobile, desktop, and tablet over the past seven
                 * days.
                 */
                function renderTopCountriesChart(ids) {
                    query({
                        'ids': ids,
                        'dimensions': 'ga:country',
                        'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
                        'sort': '-ga:sessions',
                        'max-results': 5
                    })
                            .then(function (response) {

                                var data = [];
                                var colors = ['#4D5360', '#949FB1', '#D4CCC5', '#E2EAE9', '#F7464A'];

                                response.rows.forEach(function (row, i) {
                                    data.push({
                                        label: row[0],
                                        value: +row[1],
                                        color: colors[i]
                                    });
                                });

                                new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-4-container')).Doughnut(data);
                                generateLegend('legend-4-container', data);
                            });
                }


                /**
                 * Extend the Embed APIs `gapi.analytics.report.Data` component to
                 * return a promise the is fulfilled with the value returned by the API.
                 * @param {Object} params The request parameters.
                 * @return {Promise} A promise.
                 */
                function query(params) {
                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        var data = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({query: params});
                        data.once('success', function (response) {
                            resolve(response);
                        })
                                .once('error', function (response) {
                                    reject(response);
                                })
                                .execute();
                    });
                }


                /**
                 * Create a new canvas inside the specified element. Set it to be the width
                 * and height of its container.
                 * @param {string} id The id attribute of the element to host the canvas.
                 * @return {RenderingContext} The 2D canvas context.
                 */
                function makeCanvas(id) {
                    var container = document.getElementById(id);
                    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                    container.innerHTML = '';
                    canvas.width = container.offsetWidth;
                    canvas.height = container.offsetHeight;
                    container.appendChild(canvas);

                    return ctx;
                }


                /**
                 * Create a visual legend inside the specified element based off of a
                 * Chart.js dataset.
                 * @param {string} id The id attribute of the element to host the legend.
                 * @param {Array.<Object>} items A list of labels and colors for the legend.
                 */
                function generateLegend(id, items) {
                    var legend = document.getElementById(id);
                    legend.innerHTML = items.map(function (item) {
                        var color = item.color || item.fillColor;
                        var label = item.label;
                        return '<li><i style="background:' + color + '"></i>' + label + '</li>';
                    }).join('');
                }


                // Set some global Chart.js defaults.
                Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = 60;
                Chart.defaults.global.animationEasing = 'easeInOutQuart';
                Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
                Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = false;

            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the source for that page, you can see those sample components are located here:

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/embed-api/view-selector2.js

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/embed-api/date-range-selector.js

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/embed-api/active-users.js

If you look at their Github repo, you can find them here:

https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/tree/master/assets/javascript/embed-api

Note, if you're going to use these components on your own site, you should copy the source files and not link to them. appspot.com is not a CDN and your site's performance will suffer if you do.